# Airflow DAG trigger wait_for_completion not working as expected?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have multiple DAGs that depend on `initial_dag` running first, after that I'd like the dependent DAGs to run one by one after each other. Here is what I have:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_NAME,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
)

initial_dag = BashOperator(
    task_id='initial_dag',
    bash_command="python /home/airflow/gcs/dags/task.py",
    dag=dag
)

dependent_dag1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="dependent_dag1",
    trigger_dag_id="dependent_dag1",
    wait_for_completion=True,
    dag=dag
)

dependent_dag2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="dependent_dag2",
    trigger_dag_id="dependent_dag2",
    wait_for_completion=True,
    dag=dag
)

dependent_dag3 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="dependent_dag3",
    trigger_dag_id="dependent_dag3",
    wait_for_completion=True,
    dag=dag
)

initial_dag >> dependent_dag1 >> dependent_dag2 >> dependent_dag3
```

I thought the `wait_for_completion=True` would complete the run of each DAG before triggering the next one. E.g. `initial_dag` runs and completes, then trigger `dependent_dag1` and wait for that to complete to trigger subsequent tasks.

The order the DAGs are being triggered is correct, but it doesn't seem to be waiting for the previous DAG to complete first, e.g. `dependent_dag2` is being triggered before `dependent_dag1` has been completed.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This was [answered](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/16583) on the Airflow GitHub discussion board but to bring both threads together here for other users.

Unfortunately, the `wait_for_completion` parameter isn't available as part of 1.10.x versions (see [documentation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py)) and is being handled and ignored as a generic `kwarg`.  This parameter is available starting with 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `wait_for_completion` parameter is the completion of the task and not the DAG itself. The task is marked as completed when it triggers the DAG successfully, so it won't wait for the completion of that DAG in particular.

You have at least two options:

1. Use [`ExternalTaskSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html) between the trigger calls to wait for the last task of the previous DAG.
2. Have a `TriggerDagRunOperator` at the end of the dependent DAGs. For example, the last task of `dependent_dag1` will be a `TriggerDagRunOperator` to run `dependent_dag2` and so on.

Your choice will mainly depend on the possibility to change the DAGs for option 2, and the flexibility you want to have (think that if you use option 1 you need to keep track of the last task of the dependent DAGs, but it's still more flexible).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for the previous DAG to complete first, consider using ExternalTaskSensor instead of TriggerDagRunOperator.

See documentation here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html

This operator will wait until the another DAG (or another DAG's task) is complete with a specified status (default is "success") until moving forward.